# Track if push notification sent with GCM resulted into e-commerce sale

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-cloud-messaging

I am sending push notifications with GCM in android application and tracking delivery,display and click event of every notification with google analytics.Now, I need to track whether any particular notification resulted into e-commerce sale.I have one click wallet payment system in place in the app.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to attribute user session with your push campaign. This article is a good starting point: [General Campaign & Traffic Source Attribution](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns) .
In general, you can add URL encoded campaign parameters into your push notification and then attribute your session with this campaign upon app launch. Then you can track your campaign sale events in GA console.